# Meaning of rule " <*> " in flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I have seen this and im not sure of his meaning.

`<*>` --
 Does it mean that it cover any state (Initial + all the ones declared with /x) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. See the [start conditions section](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) in the flex manual.

Note that start conditions can be declared either with `%x` or `%s`. The difference is explained in the manual section linked above.